# Is there any router or set ups that can use 2 ISPs?

Tags: router

ISP at my home is shaky. Both are unreliable.

I wonder if there is a way to have a router that can use 2 ISPs.

If one ISP is down the router will simply access the internet from the second ISP.

An automatic solution is preferred

Comment: Right off hand I would think each ISP would have its own router and router configuration so what you would need is a router for each ISP. Could you update your post to describe the actual interface of the two ISPs? Are they cable or DSL or fiber or satellite or what?

Comment: @RichardChambers, you'd need a *modem* for each, but it's quite possible to have a router that does failover between the two (I set up one back in the early days of high-speed internet that would fall back to dialup if the cable internet went down).